# Placing an image to the left of a centered line

Tags: graphics, resume

I have a resume that I created in LaTeX, and I'm very happy with the results, although the page is completely filled with text.  I sent it to a recruiter, who wants to put her logo at the top of the page.  Since the page is full, adding an image above my name would push text to the next page, which I do not want to do.

I would like the image to be at the top right of the page instead, next to my name and address line.

The preamble looks like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article} 
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage[top=0.25in, bottom=0.25in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in, ]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\setlist[itemize,1]{topsep=0.75em,itemsep=-0.2em}
\setlist[itemize,2]{topsep=-0.5em,itemsep=-0.05em, label=\ding{226}}
```

Then I put the image, and my name:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{images/recruiter-logo.png}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{center}
  {\bfseries\Large FIRST-NAME LAST-NAME, CFA} \\
  {\large Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx $\bullet$ Email: first-name.last-name@gmail.com} \\[2em]
\end{center}
```

The problem is, when I do that, the image ends up several lines below my name, not to the right of it.  Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use two top-aligned minipages with `\vspace{0pt}` at the beginning to set the reference point.

The first minipage is set inside a zero width box, so TeX won't see its actual width and the second minipage is set with `\centering`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[top=0.25in, bottom=0.25in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in, ]{geometry}

\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\setlength\parindent{0pt} 

\setlist[itemize,1]{topsep=0.75em,itemsep=-0.2em}
\setlist[itemize,2]{topsep=-0.5em,itemsep=-0.05em, label=\ding{226}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}% <--- adjust the desired width
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}% <--- replace with your image
  \end{minipage}%
}% <--- don't forget
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace{0pt}
\Large\textbf{FIRST-NAME LAST-NAME, CFA} \\
\large Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx $\bullet$ Email: first-name.last-name@gmail.com
\end{minipage}

\vspace{6ex}

The rest of the CV follows

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the image on the right, just change the order (and make the zero width box right aligned).

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[top=0.25in, bottom=0.25in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in, ]{geometry}

\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\setlength\parindent{0pt} 

\setlist[itemize,1]{topsep=0.75em,itemsep=-0.2em}
\setlist[itemize,2]{topsep=-0.5em,itemsep=-0.05em, label=\ding{226}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace{0pt}
\Large\textbf{FIRST-NAME LAST-NAME, CFA} \\
\large Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx $\bullet$ Email: first-name.last-name@gmail.com
\end{minipage}% <--- don't forget
\makebox[0pt][r]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}% <--- adjust the desired width
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}% <--- replace with your image
  \end{minipage}%
}

\vspace{6ex}

The rest of the CV follows

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is perfect, exactly what I needed.  Thank you so much for the help.  If I needed it on the right side of the page (as opposed to the left) is there a way to do that?

Comment: @linux_guest Added the code.

Answer (score 0):

To get the picture on the right hand side change parts in question of your code with these one

```
\begin{document}


\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}% <--- adjust the desired width
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}% <--- replace with your image
  \end{minipage}%

\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace{-47pt}
\Large\textbf{FIRST-NAME LAST-NAME, CFA} \\
\large Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx $\bullet$ Email: first-name.last-name@gmail.com
\end{minipage}

\vspace{6ex}

The rest of the CV follows
```